# TypeError: writeSource is not a function

Tags: javascript, import, module

I am using require to import 3 files with almost the same code, but one of them (writeToSource.js) doesn't work. I thought I was giving wrong arguments to the function, but when I checked everything is right. What can I do? I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: writeSource is not a function
    at Request._callback (/home/nika/Desktop/Girchi/Media-Girchi/assets/components/scrapOn.js:35:11)
```

Main JavaScript file:

```js
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const writeDataToGirchi = require('./writeDataToGirchi');
const writeDataToImportants = require('./writeDataToImportants');
const writeToSource = require('./writeToSource');

function scrapOn(url, accept, accept1, sourceImgUrl) {
  try {
    request(url, (error, response, html) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);

        const title = $('.article-title').text();
        const dataInfo = $('.date').first().text();
        const text = $('.article-body').text();
        const imgUrl = `https:${$('.global-figure-image  ').attr("src")}`;

        const writeGirchi = writeDataToGirchi("on.json", title, dataInfo, text, imgUrl, sourceImgUrl, url);
        const writeImportants = writeDataToImportants("on.json", title, dataInfo, text, imgUrl, sourceImgUrl, url);
        const writeSource = writeToSource("on.json", "On", title, dataInfo, text, imgUrl, sourceImgUrl, url);


        if (accept === "on" && accept1 === "on") {
          writeGirchi();
          writeImportants();
          writeSource();
        } else if (accept === "on") {
          writeImportants();
          writeSource();
        } else if (accept1 === "on") {
          writeGirchi();
          writeSource();
        } else {
          writeSource();
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

writeToSource.js file:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function writeToSource(fileName, name, title, dataInfo, text, imgUrl, sourceImgUrl, url) {
  fs.readFile(`./assets/data/${fileName}`, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    let newsData = JSON.parse(data);
    newsData[dataInfo] = {
      ...newsData[dataInfo],
      source: name,
      title: title,
      text: text,
      link: url,
      logo: sourceImgUrl,
      articleDate: dataInfo,
      imgUrl: imgUrl,
      important: false,
      fileName: fileName
    };
    newsData = JSON.stringify(newsData)
    fs.writeFileSync(`./assets/data/${fileName}`, newsData, (error) => {
      if (error) console.log(error)
    })
  });
}

module.exports = writeToSource;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writeSource is indeed not a function, it is the return value of writeToSource(...args). If you want it to be a function try this

```
const writeSource = () => { 
writeToSource("on.json", "On", title, dataInfo, text, imgUrl, sourceImgUrl, url);}
```

Comment: Got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think that is because you didn't export the function or anything in your WriteToSouce.js file

```
 export function WriteToSource(...args){
   //do your stuff
}
```

OR you could use

```
 module.exports=WriteToSource;
```

As the documentation for [require](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) says

> The basic functionality of require is that it reads a JavaScript file, executes the file, and then proceeds to return the exports

In your case you never exported the function but called it latter as a function in main js file, meaning
`const writeToSource = require('./writeToSource');` 
returns nothing and writeToSource is undefined

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had it exported in my file but forgot to write here. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I feel really stupid right now.
I just replaced `const writeSource = writeToSource()`
with an arrow function - `const writeSource = () => { writeToSource() }`

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have not exported the function writeToSource for it to be available in main.js

module.exports = writeToSource;

Created a codesandbox just to clarify how you would export it https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-browser-5lzqy?file=/src/index.js

Mocked your files and calling writeToSource from the main(index.js) works

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had it exported in my file but forgot to write here. Sorry!